# JavaFX jar execution throws invocationtargetexception

Tags: java, javafx, jar

I am working on a JavaFX application which accepts user inputs and stores it in a file. For styling the scene I am using CSS.

The IDE I'm using is netbeans using which I packed all the classes and files into a jar file

[These are all the files inside the project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzbtV.jpg)

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    String[] noti = {"Loading...","Verifying user...","Gathering info...","Success"};

    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    VBox root = new VBox();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1100, 650);

    Label label = new Label("Loading...");


    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(0.1);


    Thread thr = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try{

                Thread.sleep(1500);
                progressBar.setProgress(0.2);

            }catch(Exception e){}

        }

    });



    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    root.getChildren().addAll(progressBar, label);
    scene.getStylesheets().add( getClass().getResource("view/Main.CSS").toExternalForm() );
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\SVNPC\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\portee\\TEST_1");

    if( !file.exists() ){
        file.mkdir();         
    }

    file = new File("C:\\Users\\SVNPC\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\portee\\TEST_1\\core.txt");


    if( !file.exists() && !file.isDirectory() ){


        // Create the file and Fill it with user data


    }

    else{



    }

    primaryStage.show();
    thr.start();

}
```

Whenever I tried to execute the jar file, it throws invocationtargetexception .
I am new to JavaFX and I have no idea what is causing the jar to throw these many exceptions

[This happened when I tried to run the JAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpzjK.jpg)

Comment: Post your code about Splash.java file In the line 129 you have a NullPointerException

Comment: scene.getStylesheets().add( getClass().getResource("view/Main.CSS").toExternalForm() );

This is what I have on li:129

Comment: Are you sure scene is not null? Or getStylesheets is not null?

Comment: @fabian: Right. scene is not null. Update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your error is a `NullPointerException` on line 129 of `Splash.java` file.

You tell me your code on that line is:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add( getClass().getResource("view/Main.CSS").toExternalForm() );
```

So you must add this check before assignment:

You can guarantee scene is not null because you have in this line:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1100, 650);
```

So the check will become:

```
if (scene.getStylesheets() != null && getClass() != null
&& getClass().getResource("view/Main.CSS") != null) {
    scene.getStylesheets().add(
       getClass().getResource("view/Main.CSS").toExternalForm() );
}
```

Because the `NullPointerException` rise when you try to use a property of null object.

Comment: Now the JAR file runs like a charm bro, but the problem is that the CSS file is not loaded at all. The Scenes are getting displayed with no custom stylings